# Is there a way to get the code for a react component im importing from a library?

Tags: node-modules

Im importin AutoAdressfill from mapbox and i would like to change the way it works a bit. Is there any way to access the code?

Comment: ... It's in `node_modules`; if it's commercial software it may be obfuscated. If it's not there's likely a repo.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes it is node_modules. ill check for a repo but i don't think there is one.

Comment: @Jay The repo link is usually linked directly from the npm page if it's on npm. Is this the repo? https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js

Comment: @ionosphere No; https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/search-js-react?activeTab=code

Answer (score 0):

First, check the source code and any docs to see if the custom functionality you need is already supported through component APIs (.e.g., custom props).

Depending on your use case and what kind of changes you want to make, you could override the library CSS classes or event listeners, create a custom wrapper component, or modify the source code directly. Here's a link with some strategies for doing so: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-customize-your-third-party-react-components-e0afd88532c9/

If the library is open source, you could also consider submitting a PR.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time will look into it now.